# sympy args unexpected answer

Tags: sympy

I the following code

```
f = lambda x: 2**(x+1)
f_sym = f(sympy.symbol.symbols('x'))
print f_sym.args
```

The output is (2, x+1).

Why the output is not x?

I have some functions composed with functions like the previous one and the final expressions do not simplify:

```
f = lambda x, y: (x/y)**.5
f_sym = f(sympy.symbol.symbols('x'), sympy.symbol.symbols('y'))
symbols = f_sym.free_symbols
aux = np.asarray([sympy.derive_by_array(f_sym, symbol) for symbol in [symbols]])
uc_matrix = np.diag(sympy.symbols(','.join(['u_{%s}'%symbol for symbol in symbols])))**2
uf = ((np.dot(np.dot(aux,uc_matrix), aux.T))**.5)[0][0]
y = uf/f_sym
print (y**2).expand().simplify()
```

Answer (score 1):

In SymPy terms, `f_sym` is the expression

```
Pow(Integer(2), Add(Symbol('x'), Integer(1)))
```

as you can find from `srepr(f_sym)`. So, the function is "raising to power" and the arguments of that function are 2 and x+1.

If you want specifically the exponent, `f_sym.args[1]` will return that.

It's important to recognize that `f_sym` is not a function. It does not take any arguments and does not return anything. It's a SymPy expression. There is no special meaning of `x+1` within this expression: it's just one of its parts, like the number `2` is.

---

To answer your follow-up question: the expression will simplify to

```
u_{x}**2/(4*x**2) + u_{y}**2/(4*y**2)
```

if you use the rational number `sympy.Rational(1, 2)` instead of floating-point number `.5` in the exponent. Floating point numbers are poison for SymPy. Other ways to achieve the same effect, with less to type:

- use `sympy.sqrt` function instead of raising to power `1/2`.
- write `sympy.S(1)/2` which creates the same Rational object because 1 is turned into a SymPy object prior to division.

Reference: [Python numbers vs. SymPy Numbers](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html#python-numbers-vs-sympy-numbers)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, now i see that f_sym was not a function. Now I include on the question another example to show my issue, which may not be what I originally asked…

Comment: Thanks for your input. Now I understand the issue… My workaround (as my functions are imported and cant really rewrite them to use all sympy,rational) was to remove the sqrt from uf, and use powsimp(deep = True, force = True), then apply the sqrt.